# PyScripter Input MessageBox

Tags: python, messagebox, pyscripter

I use PyScripter for my Python programming, and I find the raw_input/input using a MessageBox for input very annoying. Is their any way to switch to getting input from writing in the console and NOT have a message box pop-up?

Comment: number= int(raw_input('Enter number: '))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people complained about it in the pyscripter's google code main page. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/issues/detail?id=311).

The issue was raised in 2009 and has not been solved till date. It is the only annoyance I found about pyscripter so far.